# ERROR: ОШИБКА: схема для создания объектов не выбрана

Tags: sql, postgresql

Делаю запрос на создание новой таблицы и добавления туда данных.
Все таблицы, схему, базу проверил, права для субъекта root и public выданы.
Postgresql используется.

Ошибка, которая появляется в консоли:

```
ERROR: ОШИБКА:  схема для создания объектов не выбрана
LINE 1: CREATE TABLE city
                     ^

SQL-состояние: 3F000
Символ: 14
```

Запрос:

```
CREATE TABLE city
(
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  id SERIAL,
  id_region integer NOT NULL,
  name varchar(250) NOT NULL

);

INSERT INTO city (id, id_region, name) VALUES
(1, 1, 'Адыгейск'),
(2, 1, 'Майкоп'),
(3, 2, 'Горно-Алтайск'),
(4, 3, 'Алейск'),
(5, 3, 'Барнаул'),
(6, 3, 'Белокуриха'),
(7, 3, 'Бийск'),
(8, 3, 'Горняк'),
(9, 3, 'Заринск'),
(10, 3, 'Змеиногорск'),
(11, 3, 'Камень-на-Оби'),
(12, 3, 'Новоалтайск'),
(13, 3, 'Рубцовск'),
(14, 3, 'Славгород'),
(15, 3, 'Яровое'),
(16, 4, 'Белогорск'),
(17, 4, 'Благовещенск'),
(18, 4, 'Завитинск'),
(19, 4, 'Зея'),
(20, 4, 'Райчихинск'),
(21, 4, 'Свободный'),
(22, 4, 'Сковородино'),
(23, 4, 'Тында'),
(24, 4, 'Шимановск'),
(25, 5, 'Архангельск'),
(26, 5, 'Вельск'),
(27, 5, 'Каргополь'),
(28, 5, 'Коряжма'),
(29, 5, 'Котлас'),
(30, 5, 'Мезень'),
(31, 5, 'Мирный'),
(32, 5, 'Новодвинск'),
(33, 5, 'Няндома'),
(34, 5, 'Онега'),
(35, 5, 'Северодвинск'),
(36, 5, 'Сольвычегодск'),
(37, 5, 'Шенкурск'),
(38, 6, 'Астрахань'),
(39, 6, 'Ахтубинск'),
(40, 6, 'Знаменск'),
(41, 6, 'Камызяк'),
(42, 6, 'Нариманов'),
(43, 6, 'Харабали'),
(44, 7, 'Агидель'),
(45, 7, 'Баймак'),
(46, 7, 'Белебей'),
(47, 7, 'Белорецк'),
(48, 7, 'Бирск'),
(49, 7, 'Благовещенск'),
(50, 7, 'Давлеканово'),
(51, 7, 'Дюртюли'),
(52, 7, 'Ишимбай'),
(53, 7, 'Кумертау'),
(54, 7, 'Межгорье'),
(55, 7, 'Мелеуз'),
(56, 7, 'Нефтекамск'),
(57, 7, 'Октябрьский'),
(58, 7, 'Салават'),
(59, 7, 'Сибай'),
(60, 7, 'Стерлитамак'),


 ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скорее всего у вас не задана схема по умолчанию.

Что возвращает

```
SHOW search_path;
```

?

Если там пусто - это оно самое.

Тогда задать типа того:

```
SET search_path TO myschema,public;
```

Comment: Тогда посмотрите тут: https://qastack.ru/dba/106057/error-no-schema-has-been-selected-to-create-in